# Azure ETag headers appear malformed

Tags: azure, cdn, etag

ETags are required to be quoted but Azure CDN generates ETags that are not quoted. Has anyone seen or do you expect problems with intermediate caches because of this?

Comment: I've noticed this too. I uploaded the item via Azure Explorer and an ETag is set by something but it is not quoted and you cannot modify it either in Explorer or in the portal. Kind of sucks!

Answer (score 0):

How do you distribute your CDN content? Are you using a Windows Azure Web Role or just CDN configuration? It would be interesting to see how do you verify the ETAG does not have quote.

I just check with both the sources and in the HTTP header they both shows within the quote so would u please check the HTTP Headers and verify how it is listed.

Comment: We run the website in a web role, but the CDN content is deployed to the blob store. It can be easily seen that the ETags are not quoted by using Fiddler to inspect the response headers. For example: [link](http://cdn.shingl.com/cdn/scripts/lib/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js) returns (other headers removed):

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 107248
Content-Type: text/javascript
Content-MD5: Ro73Rk3SB5KtY1hGfTCxTQ==
ETag: 0x8CF542BA0DD572A
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0